# viewWillTransitionToSize: vs willTransitionToTraitCollection:

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, rotation, uikit

Can anyone explain the differences between these 2 methods? [The docs for UIViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/) explicitly state that viewWillTransitionToSize should be used for managing rotations, but clicking through to the [UIContentContainer page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIContentContainer_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIContentContainer/viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:), the *willTransitionToTraitCollection* method makes a confusing entrance.

I think I understand the conceptual difference between a size class change ( trait collection change ) and a size change, but I'm not sure which method to implement in which circumstances. Clarification from a UIKit wizard would be helpful!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Whenever you want to do something aa a response to a user rotating their device you should use `viewWillTransitionToSize`, if you do that you know for sure that your actions are executed as this is called every time your app's window changes size.

If you only want to take action when the trait collection changes, for instance if you have a certain `collectionViewLayout` set for a `Compact` size class and another you want to use for `Regular` you use `willTransitionToTraitCollection`.

If the trait collection changes then the size also changes. But it doesn't work the other way around. A portrait iPad and a landscape iPad have the same traits but are different sizes. Add multitasking to the mix and you have a whole variety of sizes that would map to just two `traitCollection` size classes.

Comment: I thought to ask, to have different layout when device rotation happens, we update constraints in `willTransitionToTraitCollection` not `traitCollectionDidChange`, right? or it doesn't matter?

Comment: For rotation you would update in `viewWillTransitionToSize`, depending on the device you might not get a new trait collection when the device rotates. For example, iPad full screen apps are Regular/Regular in both orientations

Comment: so what is it the difference between `viewWillTransitionToSize`, `willTransitionToTraitCollection`? When to use one over another?

Comment: and I see now that `viewWillTransitionToSize` doesn't give me information about the next traitCollection so I cannot - for example - know if I am rotating from Portrait to Landscape in iPhone devices . so in this case I should use `willTransitionToTraitCollection`, right?